# error C1075: no missing brace -- error still shows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

This one is really confusing, I only have 19 lines of code, yet I still get the error C1075 and C2143...

**Error 1   error C2143:** syntax error : missing ';' before 'using'    E:\CS 10\VisualStudio2010\~EmpireBuilder~\Empire Builder\Empire Builder\Empire Builder.cpp  6   1   Empire Builder

**Error 2   error C1075:** end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'e:\cs 10\visualstudio2010\~empirebuilder~\empire builder\empire builder\MainMenu.h(28)' was matched  E:\CS 10\VisualStudio2010\~EmpireBuilder~\Empire Builder\Empire Builder\Empire Builder.cpp  20  1   Empire Builder**

I MainMenu.h has no errors, nothing else is giving me errors and I cannot see any unpaired code segments.

```
// Empire Builder.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"

using namespace EmpireBuilder;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, i had this once. The problem was, that i had strange invisible characters in the file. Delete the file and re-write it (NOT COPY PASTE!). Should go pretty fast for this one ;).

Comment: In a copy-paste of the code from the web page, I don't see any unusual characters. Please copy-paste the exact error messages. (Please don't make us look up what C1075 and C2143 are.)